# Do Poincaré residue and integrable log connection commute?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

**Here are some basic notations and definitions: (ignore this part if familiar)**

1.Let $(X,\omega)$ be a compact Kähler manifold of dimension $n$, and let $D=\sum_{i=1}^r D_i$ be a simple normal crossing divisor on it, i.e., a divisor with smooth components $D_i$ intersecting each other transversally in $X$.
Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a locally free coherent sheaf on $X$ and let
$$\nabla:\mathcal{V}\to \Omega^1_X(\log D)\otimes\mathcal{V}$$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map satisfying
\begin{align}\nabla(f\cdot e)=f\cdot\nabla e+df\otimes e.\end{align}
One defines
$$\nabla_a:\Omega^a_X(\log D)\otimes \mathcal{V}\to \Omega^{a+1}_X(\log D)\otimes \mathcal{V}$$
by the rule
$$\nabla_a (\omega\otimes e)=d\omega\otimes e+(-1)^a \omega\wedge \nabla e.$$
We assume that $\nabla_{a+1}\circ\nabla_a=0$ for all $a$. Such $\nabla$ will be called an integrable logarithmic connection along $D$, or just a connection.
When $\omega\in A^{0,q}(X,\Omega_X^p(\log D))$, by taking $\diamondsuit=\nabla+\bar{\partial}_\mathcal{V}$, we have
$$\nabla(\omega\otimes e)=\partial\omega\otimes e+{(-1)}^{p+q}\omega\wedge\nabla(e),$$
$$\bar\partial_\mathcal{V}(\omega\otimes e)=\bar\partial\omega\otimes e.$$
2.For any $\alpha\in A^{0,q}(X,\Omega^p_X(\log D))$, we can write
\begin{align}\label{expression of alpha}
\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2\wedge\frac{dz^1}{z^1}
\end{align}
on $U$, where $\alpha_1$ does not contain $dz^1$ and $\alpha_2\in A^{0,q}(U,\Omega^{p-1}_X(\log \sum_{i=2}^rD_i))$. Denoting by
$$\iota_{D_i}:D_i\hookrightarrow X$$
the natural inclusion, without loss of generality, we may assume that $$\{z^1=0\}=D_1\cap U,$$ and set
$$\label{defnRes}
\text{Res}_{D_1}(\alpha)=\iota^*_{D_1}(\alpha_2)    
$$
on $D_1\cap U$. Then $\text{Res}_{D_1}(\alpha)$ is globally well-defined and
$$
\text{Res}_{D_1}(\alpha)\in A^{0,q}(D_1,\Omega^{p-1}_{D_1}(\log \sum_{i=2}^r D_i\cap D_1)). 
$$
Set the so-called Poincaré residue as
$$
\text{Res}(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^r\text{Res}_{D_i}(\alpha).
$$
3.For an integrable log connection $\nabla$, we also define the residue map along $D_1$ to be the composed map:

$$\text{Res}_{D_1}(\nabla):\mathcal V\xrightarrow{\nabla} \Omega_X^1(\log D)\otimes\mathcal V\xrightarrow{\text{Res}_{D_1}\otimes\text{id}_\mathcal V}\mathcal O_{D_1}\otimes\mathcal V$$

---

**Question:**
Then now, for $\beta\in A^{0,q}(X,\Omega_X^p(\log D)\otimes\mathcal V),$
we first have the composed map acting on $\beta:$
$$\text{Res}_{D_1}(\nabla):A^{0,q}(X,\Omega_X^p(\log D)\otimes\mathcal V)\xrightarrow{\nabla} A^{0,q}(X,\Omega_X^{p+1}(\log D)\otimes\mathcal V)\xrightarrow{\text{Res}_{D_1}\otimes\text{id}_\mathcal V} A^{0,q}(D_1,\Omega_{D_1}^{p}(\log(\sum_{i=2}^{r} ({D_i}\cap {D_1}))\otimes\mathcal V)$$

Naturally, we also can let $\text{Res}_{D_1}\otimes\text{id}_\mathcal V$ **first** act on $\beta$, as $$\gamma=(\text{Res}_{D_1}\otimes\text{id}_\mathcal V)(\beta)\in A^{0,q}(D_1,\Omega_{D_1}^{p-1}(\log(\sum_{i=2}^{r} ({D_i}\cap {D_1}))\otimes\mathcal V).$$

**Then my question is,** can we find some induced integrable log connection $\nabla^\prime$ acting on $\gamma$ satisfying $$\nabla^\prime(\gamma)=\text{Res}_{D_1}(\nabla)(\beta),$$
i.e., do $\text{Res}\otimes\text{id}_\mathcal V$ and $\nabla$ commute in some sense?

Any suggestion and references will be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $p=0$ then $\gamma=0$ whereas $Res(\nabla)(\beta)$ is not I guess.

Comment: Dear @GTA, thanks for your comment. But I notice that in H. Esnault, E. Viehweg: Lectures on Vanishing Theorems page 12 line -5, the definition of $\text{Res}$, we always let $p\ge 1$ as convention. So in this situation, do you have any futher suggestion?